# how to check login

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android programming.So,I have no idea how to check my login by using PHP. NullPointerException is also appear.I don't know what should I do.Please help for login code. 
That's my Jason code.

```
public void jsonen()
    {



        ArrayList<NameValuePair> pp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID","409"));


        String result = response.toString();// store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query

        Log.i("response", response);
        try{
            JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject (result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                  int status = jArray.getInt("requestStatus");
            }

    }
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok (looks horrible actually - well to many if statements and the goto mixed in) and I can't see anything obvious on a php side.

You are using global function db_connect() so make sure that this returns a link to DB.

Other then that you want to read about sql injection:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php